# Pass hash to a function that accepts keyword arguments

Tags: ruby, hash, keyword-argument

I have a hash like this `hash = {"band" => "for King & Country", "song_name" => "Matter"}` and a class:

```
class Song
  def initialize(*args, **kwargs)
    #accept either just args or just kwargs
    #initialize @band, @song_name
  end
end
```

I would want to pass the `hash` as keyword arguments like `Song.new band: "for King & Country", song_name: "Matter"` Is it possible?

Comment: You have to use symbolic keys, i.e. `hash = {band: "for King & Country", song_name: "Matter"}`.

Comment: @Stefan I get the `hash` from `.yml` file and that's what it returns.

Comment: Is the YAML file fixed or can you change it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to convert the keys in your hash to symbols:

```
class Song
  def initialize(*args, **kwargs)
    puts "args = #{args.inspect}"
    puts "kwargs = #{kwargs.inspect}"
  end
end

hash = {"band" => "for King & Country", "song_name" => "Matter"}

Song.new(hash)
# Output:
# args = [{"band"=>"for King & Country", "song_name"=>"Matter"}]
# kwargs = {}

symbolic_hash = hash.map { |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }.to_h
#=> {:band=>"for King & Country", :song_name=>"Matter"}

Song.new(symbolic_hash)
# Output:
# args = []
# kwargs = {:band=>"for King & Country", :song_name=>"Matter"}
```

In Rails / Active Support there is [`Hash#symbolize_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys)

Comment: Another approach, hash.keys.each { |k| hash[k.to_sym]=hash.delete(k) }

Comment: @SteeveMcCauley nowadays you can use `hash.transform_values!(&:to_sym)` and you should pass it via `Song.new(**symbolic_hash)`

Comment: Um, doesn't that convert the values to symbols, not the keys?

Comment: @SteeveMcCauley yes indeed  it should of course be `hash.transform_keys!(&:to_sym)`

Comment: Yeah, I grokked that eventually :)  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As Stefan mentions, in Rails we have access to `symbolize_keys` that works like this:

```
{"band" => "for King & Country", "song_name" => "Matter"}.symbolize_keys
#=> {:band=>"for King & Country", :song_name=>"Matter"}
```

It's also aliased as: `to_options`, hence:

```
{"band" => "for King & Country", "song_name" => "Matter"}.to_options
#=> {:band=>"for King & Country", :song_name=>"Matter"}
```